# Limiting Number of Submission Per User Id in Joomla for 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date, joomla

We have a form in joomla built using RSform pro.
There is a script which can limit the total submissions by a registered member to 5 submissions.

```
 // Define the maximum number of submissions.
 $max = 5;
 $user = JFactory::getUser();
 $db   = JFactory::getDbo();
 $query   = $db->getQuery(true);

 // Setup the query.
$query->select('COUNT('.$db->qn('UserId').')')
->from($db->qn('#__rsform_submissions'))
->where($db->qn('FormId').'='.$db->q($formId))
->where($db->qn('UserId').'='.$db->q($user->get('id')));

$db->setQuery($query);
 $counter = $db->loadResult();

if ($counter >= $max){
$formLayout = '<p style="color:red;">Rejected</p>';
  }
```

However - we have to modify it so that :- > Maximum Submission clause remains for 24 hours - 
A User can do maximum 5 submissions in 24 hours from the time of first submission done - and the limit to go off automatically after 24 hours

Any suggestions or help !!

Answer (score 0):

Create a field in database with submission time as (int) and insert time using php time() function and compare time on every submission using current_time-last_post_time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the creation date of each submissions that is saved to your database.

so for example add a field to your table called `createdDate` as `DATETIME`

and then make sure you update the `INSERT` to pass in `DATE()` so the current time is saved into it when a submission is saved.

Then you can use something like this :

```
$query->select('COUNT('.$db->qn('UserId').')')
->from($db->qn('#__rsform_submissions'))
->where($db->qn('FormId').'='.$db->q($formId))
->where($db->qn('UserId').'='.$db->q($user->get('id')));
->where($db->qn('createDate').'=> DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)'));
```

To get all submissions in the last 24 hours for that UserId

You count the results :

```
$db->setQuery($query);
 $counter = $db->loadResult();
```

you may need to use `count($counter)` to get the total.
I'm not sure how your loadResult() function returns data.